# Cargar diferentes URLs sin cerrar el navegador

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Mediante este código, cargo diferentes URLs en el navegador para extraer la fuente, pero cierro el navegador tras cada lectura, ¿se puede hacer un reload con la siguiente URL de la lista?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

delFichero = file('listado.txt', 'r')

for n in delFichero:

    URL = str(n)

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(URL)
    content = browser.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias chicos¡¡ A ambos. El otro dia vi que habia caibado la declaracion del parser, pero no he tenido mucho tiempo para sentarme, es un plugin que me estoy haciendo con el poco a poco. Por cierto, ¿sabeis si se podria leer el fuente de webs como? http://www.tennisabstract.com/cgi-bin/wplayer.cgi?p=CarolineWozniacki La tengo pendiente hace siglos. Si accedo a los js veo los datos con los que se calculan las vistas, pero desconozco las forumlas empleadas. Muchisimas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solo tendrías que modificar un poco tu código. Crea `browser` fuera del bucle y ciérralo fuera del bucle. Algo como esto:

```
from selenium import webdriver


urls = [
    'https://www.google.com',
    'https://duckduckgo.com'
]
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
fuentes = {}

for url in urls:
    browser.get(url)
    fuentes[url] = browser.page_source

browser.quit()
```

Con esto ya tienes la fuente para cada URL:

```
print fuentes['https://www.google.com'][:100]
```

Daría como resultado:

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="es-419"><head><meta content="/images/b
```

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes. De paso algunas modificaciones a tu código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("listado.txt", "r") as delFichero:

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for linea in delFichero:
        url = linea.strip()
        browser.get(url)
        content = browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        print(url)

    browser.quit()
```

En primer lugar usamos un [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#module-contextlib) para manejar la lectura del archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
with open("listado.txt", "r") as delFichero
```

De esta forma es mucho más seguro ya que podemos olvidarnos de cerrar el archivo , de hecho tu te olvidaste de agregar el close. El [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#module-contextlib) sabe cuando ya has dejado de leer en este caso y cierra automáticamente el archivo.

Un detalle, al hacer esto: `url = linea.strip()` quitamos los saltos de línea que leímos del archivo, en tu código pareciera que no es necesario pero siempre es un buen detalle.

La instanciación de `BeautifulSoup` ha cambiado, y debe hacerse así:  `BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")` especificando el "parser" apropiado.

Si analizas el nuevo código verás que ahora el `browser.quit()` esta fuera del ciclo, por lo que el navehador no se cerrará hasta haber completado el mismo.